# Custom Hibernate Persistence Provider with JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: hibernate, jboss, jboss7.x

We have a Java EE 6 application currently running in JBoss 6. The application uses a customized Hibernate persistence provider in the 'persistence.xml'

The customized persistence provider class inherits from org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.

The customized persistence provider is packaged in the application 'ear' file.

Now when deploying the application to JBoss 7.1.1 following exception occurs:

```
08:50:14,766 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Failed to define class my.custom.HibernatePersistence in Module "deployment.ear.ear:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link my/custom/HibernatePersistence (Module "deployment.ear.ear:main" from Service Module Loader)
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderProcessor.deploy(PersistenceProviderProcessor.java:76)
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/ejb/HibernatePersistence
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence from [Module "deployment.ear.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
  ... 20 more
08:50:14,789 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ear.ear".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ear.ear".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "ear.ear"
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011426: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'my.custom.HibernatePersistence'
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderProcessor.deploy(PersistenceProviderProcessor.java:91)
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
  ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.custom.HibernatePersistence from [Module "deployment.ear.ear:main" from Service Module Loader]
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
  at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderProcessor.deploy(PersistenceProviderProcessor.java:76)
  ... 6 more
```

What are we doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This could be as simple as adding a dependency to `org.hibernate` to your `MANIFEST.MF`. It also could be that your custom provider is not in the correct directory, `EAR/lib` is where it's expected by default.

Have a look at the [class loading documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7) first. Specifically in your case the [EAR class loading](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7#ClassLoadinginAS7-EARClassLoading).